# Trying to turn a time series into stat on Grafana

Tags: prometheus, grafana

I'm new to Grafana and I'm trying to turn a time series that I have into a Stat on Grafana, but when I make it, I got zero.

The below picture shows how is the graph when I select the time series.

[image]

This is the picture when I try to change to Stat.

[image]

I already tried to use teh "sum" and "count" inside the Metrics browser but it returns 0 and 1, respectively.

I even tried to the metrics inside the explore and after pressing the "Run query" to check but I don't have anything displayed.

[image]

Unfortunetaly it's my first time using Grafana, so I don't know much about it.

Please, let me know if anything else is needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *Stat* panel transforms your time series into a single value.

In the panel options, you can choose how that is done under `Value options` -> `Calculation`.

In your case, probably the calculation `Last` is selected, since it is displaying `0` and your time series also ends with `0`. Change it to the calculation you want to have displayed.